# How do I apply css to text separated by commas inside of a textarea tag? (React.js Project)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, split

Desired result:

[image: desired result]

---

I'm trying to highlight text separated by commas inside of a textarea tag (in a React project).

I really can't figure out how to accomplish this, yet every solution I've come across online uses jQuery (I really don't want to inject jQuery halfway through my project).

This is the function I currently have to trim the input values and split them:

```
handleTags = async (event) => {
    let tags = event.target.value.toLowerCase().trim().replace(/[^\w,-]/g, '')
    tags = tags.split(",")
    await this.setState({post: {...this.state.post, tags: tags}})
}
```

And this is the JSX for the textarea within my `render() {...}` function:

```
<Card.Footer className="quickpost-tags-container">
 <textarea
   onChange={event => this.handleTags(event)}
   className="postbox-tags-textarea"
   placeholder="science, non-fiction, etc..."
   contentEditable
   suppressContentEditableWarning>
 </textarea>
</Card.Footer>
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Note you cant do that not with textarea anyway. The native textarea element doesnt allow for child elements, so there isnt anything except actual text to style. And you cant have separate styles for individual parts of that text, at least not in the way you want. You would need to build your own component, use a different element like contentediable div, or use a library that has built their own

Comment: Hm. That's a shame, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So I understand that this question was a bit meh, didn't make much sense **and** made me sound like a massive noob (it was like 4 in the morning). I was trying to get the tags that the user would put in to render the same as [***refer to the image in the question***]

I was able to conditionally render a `span` element above the textarea which would render each tag within a `span` element, dynamically. This achieved the desired result.

[image]

Hopefully, this will be helpful to someone looking to solve a similar problem.